# How can I find out / test what it fastest

Tags: javascript

*How can I **test** what is fastest?*

I want to test which of the two functions are fastest:

```
function foo ( selector ) {

    var $selector = $(selector);

}
```

or

```
function foo ( selector ) {

    var $selector;

    if ( selector instanceof jQuery ) {
         $selector = selector;
    } else if ( selector ) {
         $selector = $(selector);
    }
}
```

Using the following tests:

```
foo( "div#primary" );
foo( $("div#primary") );
```

Solutions could be:

- Ask what is fastest on SO.
- Lookup the jQuery source.
- But...

...as a hypothetical question, how can I run a test in JavaScript to see if there is a speed difference?

Comment: I know this is a hypothetical question, but `typeof` would never return `'jQuery'` :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method of profiling is to record the time before the function and record it after, subtract the former from the latter.  Repeat this several times and you will have a rough idea.  There are interfering factors, like current CPU usage, that can affect the outcome though.  The browser's console might help you here:

```
console.time("test");

// ... js code here ...

console.timeEnd("test");
//-> "test: 25ms"
```

You may also be able to profile using your browser's developer tools.

The other option is to let http://jsperf.com do the profiling for you.  jsPerf runs your code repeatedly and gives you a nice comparison between your test cases.  It also records the results for each browser (based on the user agent string), so you can quickly compare the code in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I used google for this: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/20/performance-profiling-javascript/
Or in IE9, F12 and use the Profiler. I think this is also in firebug and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try jsperf -> [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing this many thousands of times it really doesn't matter.

So just go with the one that's easiest to read (i.e. #1)